# Bayesian Inference on a Normal Distribution. Unknown Variance, Known Mean. Scaled Inverse Chi squared as a Conjugate Prior

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, inference, conjugate-prior

A common prior for the unknown variance of a normal distribution (with given mean $\mu$) is the scaled inverse $\chi-$squared distribution. It turns out this is a conjugate prior! A simple proof can be found here https://real-statistics.com/bayesian-statistics/bayesian-statistics-normal-data/conjugate-priors-normal-distribution/normal-conjugate-priors-proofs/ . However it seems (given the prior is Scaled-Inv-$\chi^2(v_0,s_0^2)$ and we have $n$ samples) that the posterior should be  Scaled-Inv-$\chi^2(v_1,s_1^2)$ with

$$v_1=v_0+n,~~~s_1^2=\frac{n}{v_1}s^2+\frac{v_0}{v_1}s_0^2,$$

where

$$s^2=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\mu).$$

However this is not what is given in the link I provided. Which one is correct?